# Drupal: how to correctly add a 'class' array to an element's 'attributes' array?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

I've got a module that builds a menu. I'd like to add css classes to the `<a>` tags this module generates.

I've used `dpm()` to find the right array I need to add my classes to. This is

`['#localized_options']['attributes']`

There already is a `[title]` array in there, but no array for classes.

I've tried adding my classes a few different ways, as such:

```
$item['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'] = "some-styles";

$item['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = "some-styles";

$item['#localized_options']['attributes'] = array('class' => "some-styles");
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Would anyone one know how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Form api, the properties should start with a # prefix.
So I think the right way is:

```
$item['#localized_options']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'some-styles';
```

reference: 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#attributes

PS: do not use

```
$item['#localized_options']['#attributes'] = array('class' => "some-styles");
```

Otherwise you will erase complitely the `#attributes` just for adding your css styles! This is wrong as many other modules may add their own #attributes properties!